# gzip request from Play Framework's WSClient

Tags: web-services, http, playframework, ws-client

I'm trying to call a webservice using the `WSClient` API from Play Framework. 
The main issue is that I want to transfer huge JSON payloads (more than 2MB) without exceeding the maximal payload size.

To do so, I would like to compress the request using gzip (with the HTTP header `Content-Encoding: gzip`). In the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWS), the parameter `play.ws.compressionEnabled` is mentioned, but it only seems to enable WSResponse compression.

I have tried to manually compress the payload (using a GZipOutputStream) and to put the header `Content-Encoding:gzip`, but the server throws a `io.netty.handler.codec.compression.DecompressionException : Unsupported compression method 191 in the GZIP header`.

How could I correctly compress my request ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think I read somewhere that you can configure the WSClient to enable this but haven't tried so not 100% - see `play.ws.compressionEnabled` at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaWS#Configuring-WS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think you can compress the request (it is not supported by Netty, the underlying library). You can find more info in https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client/issues/93 and https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/2132